# Log4j2 - Rolling inside a zip file

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to find a way to roll the log daily inside a compressed file using the parameters available (no custom appenders). I.E:

```
log_folder
|-app.log
|-app.log.zip
  |-app-2015-07-28.log
  |-app-2015-07-27.log
```

Using a suffix .zip on filePattern parameter will compact the log file but  generates one file/day.

```
log_folder
|-app.log
|-app-2015-07-28.log.zip
|-app-2015-07-27.log.zip
```

Any clues on this?

Comment: Don't believe this is natively possible